# $<SEMICOLON> in cmake macro definition breaks compiler definitions

Tags: cmake

I am defining a macro in cmake for use in a third-party library to override a type. The third-party library has this code to substitute out which `optional` type it uses:

```
// If need another optional type, define the macro MAGIC_ENUM_USING_ALIAS_OPTIONAL.
#if defined(MAGIC_ENUM_USING_ALIAS_OPTIONAL)
MAGIC_ENUM_USING_ALIAS_OPTIONAL
#else
template <typename T>
using optional = std::optional<T>;
#endif
```

My cmake looks like this:

```
set(OPTIONAL_DEFINE_VALUE "template <typename T>using optional = nonstd::optional<T>\\$<SEMICOLON>;")

target_compile_definitions(magic_enum
INTERFACE
    -DMAGIC_ENUM_USING_ALIAS_OPTIONAL=${OPTIONAL_DEFINE_VALUE}
)
```

This successfully puts the semicolon at the end of the definition. However, to my surprise, the macro expands to also include the subsequent compiler directive (`TEST_INFRASTRUCTURE_ENABLED`).

[image]

The `\\$<SEMICOLON>` has seemingly broken the parsing of the compiler directive list. Is this a bug or am I just using this incorrectly?

Comment: Why do you **escape** `$<SEMICOLON>` with ``\\``? This is not a variable dereference but a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), it is not a part of CMake grammar. Also, why do you put literal `;` after it? You already have the semicolon, why do you add another one?

Comment: If I don't escape the `$<SEMICOLON>`, it doesn't expand to a semicolon in the compile (seems to just disappear, in fact). The extra `;` was a typo and has been removed. The `;` seemed to have no effect on the macro expansion anyways (the character just disappears).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. The fix was to simply add a space at the end of the string.

```
"template <typename T>using optional = nonstd::optional<T>\\$<SEMICOLON> "
                                        fun new space to fix things ~~~~^
```

I'm not sure of the exact cause, but I can speculate that having two semicolons next to each other in the compiler directive list causes some sort of cancelling-out, thus breaking the parsing and combining two directives together.